# Закрывающийся тег php ?>

Tags: php

Не раз видел что в файлах пхп нет закрывающегося тега **?>**

```
<?php

//код

//закрывающегося тега нет
```

С чем это связано и как правильно писать?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Дык а [документация по php](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) для кого? ;)

> Если файл содержит только код PHP, предпочтительно опустить закрывающий тег в конце файла. Это помогает избежать добавления случайных символов пробела или перевода строки после закрывающего тега PHP, которые могут послужить причиной нежелательных эффектов, так как PHP начинает выводить данные в буфер при отсутствии намерения у программиста выводить какие-либо данные в этой точке скрипта.

Answer (score 9):

> Как правильно писать?

И так и так будет правильно. Закрывающие теги обязательны для html файлов содержащих php код(хотя правильней будет сказать "php файлов содержащих html код). Но если у Вас файл только с php кодом, то закрывающий тег ставить не обязательно.

Если вдаваться в подробности, то для вывода php, серверу нужно не просто отдать браузеру файл "как есть"(как в случае с html) а вызвать php интерпретатор. PHP интерпретатор будет считывать(и выполнять) код до тех пор пока не встретит закрывающий тег или пока не встретит конец файла. Так что можете использовать и не использовать закрывающие теги.

Comment: То есть в современном PHP 8+ нет нужды опускать закрывающий тег, как это расписано здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410704/why-would-one-omit-the-close-tag ?