# Как удалить файл с помощью php, ajax и jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, файлы

На сервере php с функцией удаления.

Comment: Никак. надо еще на сервере чтобы что-то было.

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста:

1) удаляемый файл на сервере ведь?

2) о безопасности, хакерах и дураках сейчас не думаем?

Comment: Безопасность - иллюзия. О дураках позабочусь. А от хорошего хакера только лом и поможет :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё равно мало данных, удалить можно просто, вопрос какие файлы вы хотите удалять и прочее

Например:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" /><button class="delete">Удалить</button>
```

js:

```
$('.delete').click(function() {$.post('delfile.php',{file: $(this).prev().val()})});
```

delfile.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST('file')) unlink('dirname/'.basename($_POST['file']));
```

Comment: ?>
Забыли в конце PHP-файла.

Comment: нет не забыл, `?>` не нужно и даже вредно

Comment: Если кому-то, как и мне, интересно, почему не нужно ставить `?>` в конце файла — [Закрывающийся тег php ?>](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/186307)

Comment: @Indev Не стоит ставить ?> потому что скрипт читается до конца, если нет этого сочетания символов, а если ты код прописал после этого сочетания, то скрипт его игнорирует